# Why won't Jupyter Notebook load the module "mlwpy"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to set up an environment on Jupyter Notebook but I can't load a module (mlwpy)  that is needed.

I have tried to pip install scikit-learn in hopes that it would have the module that I was looking to use.

## what I have tried

```
from mlwpy import *
%matplotlib inline
```

## What I am getting in return

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-10-3489a3655c97> in <module>
----> 1 from mlwpy import *
2 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mlwpy
```

I expecting to get the definition from mlwpy.py included in my notebook environment.

Any ideas or help would great.

Answer (score 3):

`mlwpy` is not a Python's built-in library, nor an external library you can install with `pip` or `conda`. It looks like a custom python file you would like to import.

To run `from mlwpy import *`, you need to have a python script named `mlwpy.py` in the same directory as your Jupyter notebook file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the book's publisher notes, a link to his [github repo](https://github.com/mfenner1/mlwpy_code):

that contains all the jupyter notebook files as well as the [mlwpy file](https://github.com/mfenner1/mlwpy_code/blob/master/mlwpy.py) you are looking for (put that in the same directory as your jupyter notebook):

Answer (score 0):

This file is not a package it is a directory. If you need this file you have two basic options.

**ONE:**
If you know how to use git you can clone the directory.

**TWO:**
You can download the zip file and place it in your working directory and unzip it.

If you need to find out what your current working directory is use this code in Jupyter:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 0):

i have ran into that issue myself. what you need to do first is open up a new jupyter notebook and type in pwd. that is where you will find the current working dirctory. the next to do is to download a copy of mlwpy as a python file(as the file is not saved as a py file initially). then for the last step, you will move that downloaded python file into the directory named. I tried it and it worked.